# XPath & Replace Exact Match

Tags: xpath

can anyone help me with this?

I'm trying to change fields that have a "0" to Nothing.

I have this:

```
[str_replace("0",",{price[1]/sale[1]})]
```

but I think this will replace all fields that "contain" a 0 so for example if it had 301 then it would become 31. What I want is to only replace fields that only contain a single 0 to nothing.

How can I do this? (the code needs to be on a single line as it's run on a form field)

Comment: The code sample you posted is not XPath. Using XPath it is quite simple to replace a value (using `replace()`, surprisingly). Also, if you use XPath you most like have some XML data, would be good if you would post some sample data as well

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this may be as follows (not tested!):

```
[{string(price[1][number(sale[1]) != 0]/sale[1])}]
```

This expression includes an additional condition to only find the number if it is not 0 in the first place. If found it returns the number, otherwise it will return an empty string since the function `string` of an empty node set should yield exactly this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback.Unfortunatly this is not working. It does get rid of the "0" but the problem is it also deletes the sale price for products that have a sale price higher than 0. For example if a product has a retail price of $50 and a sale price of $35 then the sale price now becomes "0".

Comment: Could you include one example of a `sale` tag into your question?

Comment: Here is one example but this one has a zero sale price already: -<price currency="USD">
<sale end_date="" begin_date="">0.00</sale>
<retail>98.00</retail>
</price>

Comment: I just checked my XPath expression in a simple XSLT 1.0 using `xsltproc`. It works there. Which XPath processor do you use?